# Why format.dateFormat can't be assigned as String?

Tags: swift, date, datetime, format, dateformatter

I want to get current date/time in some specific format.

For example, this format is correct:

```swift
let date = Date()
let format = DateFormatter()
format.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
let formattedDate = format.string(from: date)
```

But, when I try to do like this, I got error:

```swift
func getCurrentDateTime(format: String = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") -> String {
    let date = Date()
    let format = DateFormatter()
    format.dateFormat = format       // Error: Cannot assign value of type 'DateFormatter' to type 'String?'
    return format.string(from: date)
}
```

"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" - is not a String? In this context:

```swift
format.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
```

What should be the format here?

Comment: Name of the parameter `format: String = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"` and `let format = DateFormatter()` is same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've just made a minor error in your code.  You've named your parameter `format`, but you use a variable named `format` in the code.

Just change the parameter name to something else (like `formatString`) and it will work:

```
func getCurrentDateTime(formatString: String = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") -> String {
    let date = Date()
    let format = DateFormatter()
    format.dateFormat = formatString
    return format.string(from: date)
}
```